Keycloak infinite redirect loop on iframe callback when logging in
This issue started after noticing chrome blocking third party cookies and iframes.
From my understanding, keycloak injects an iframe into the dom which is used to do a silent check, login, then return the token.
This is my _kc.init:
  _kc
    .init({
      onLoad: 'check-sso',
      responseMode: 'query',
      flow: 'implicit',
      checkLoginIframe: false,
      silentCheckSsoFallback: false,
      silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html',
      pkceMethod: 'S256',
    })

setting silentCheckSsoFallback: false, stops the infinite redirects, however, then it no longer does the silent check fallback to actually return the callback which leads to the user not being authenticated.
Then the url changes to:
http://localhost:3012/voting/voter/dashboard?session_state=...
With a blank screen
And I see this in the console:
Refused to frame 'https://<my-correct-url>.ca/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

requestStorageAccess: Must be handling a user gesture to use.
requestStorageAccess: Permission denied.
requestStorageAccess: Must be handling a user gesture to use.

Ive checked our live dev server, it does not have this issue because its behind https.
You need to use HTTPS because some vital cookies are blocked or rejected during authentication. This is due to the same site cookie protection scheme that was added to browsers for a few years ago.
I am not sure how to handle this on local.
when adding checkLoginIframe: false, it stopped the redirects, but then when I actually tried to login with credentials, the page doesnt redirect to the dashboard because the user is still not authenticated in the frontend without the callback token from KC.
Ive tried updating flow, responseMode and silentCheckSsoFallback.
Ive turned off the chrome setting to allow cookies, and this fixes the problem obviously.
UPDATE:
So I think I figured it out.
These were the 3 main causes of this problem: chrome blocking cookies, http, and initializing 2 kc instances simultaneously in the index.
(the urls were fighting between eachother)
KC reads from, localstorage > cookies > url.
Thats what the iniital KC step1.html does, it just looks at the code and tries to use localstorage but thats what that error message in the console is "permission denied", iframes can't use local storage on http sites.
Because cookies are blocked, kc was writing to the third option in the url, this is what which then causes a refresh 2x.
So kc defaulted from getting form url, because I ran both kcs at the same time, it was changing the url between the 2 instances.
However, the main issue was, I was initializing both kcs in parallel, but thats not 100% the issue, the issue was then caused by Chrome disabling reading from third party iframes. Otherwise, running in parallel would be fine. But eventually needs to be replaced because KC client will be deprecated next year.
So now I have them initializing in their respective routes, not to fight with the url. The issue remains that the browser on http will have to make a second call to return the token still, so it refreshes twice. (https will not do this)

Could you please provide more details on how to reproduce the infinite callback issue you're experiencing? More specific information would be very helpful.
